# Is Wiki wrong on Dirichlet Chararcters Modulo $10$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

[Wiki says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_character#Modulus_10):

> **Modulus 10**
>
> There are $\phi(10)=4$ characters modulo $10$.
> [image: copy pasted from the wiki page, sorry I was lazy...]
>
> Note that $χ$ is wholly determined by $\chi(3)$, since **$3$** generates the group of units modulo $10$.

I can imagine that $\chi_2$ or  $\chi_4$ generate  $\chi$, by a certain kind of multiplication. But $3$? Is Wiki wrong? Maybe they started the table with $0$ once ago...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're misunderstanding: the values of a Dirichlet character $\chi(n)$ for any $n$ are determined by $\chi(3)$, because $3$ is a generator of $(\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z})^\times$.

It is also true that the collection of Dirichlet characters modulo $m$ forms a group under (pointwise) multiplication, which in fact is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^\times$. When $m=10$, we have $(\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z})^\times\cong\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ and the characters listed in the table as $\chi_2$ and $\chi_4$ are generators.

Comment: Ah as $\chi(7)$ does...What about about my observation about $\chi_2$?

Comment: @draks: I've addressed that in my answer.

Comment: @draks... As Zev wrote "$\chi_2$ and $\chi_4$ are generators" of the group of characters.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mistaking $\chi(3)$ for $\chi_3$. It doesn't say $\chi_3$ generates anything. It says $\chi(3)$ determines $\chi(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: Thanks I see now. What about about my observation about $\chi_2$?

Comment: I see others have validated your observation about $\chi_2$.